# Registering SharePoint Event Receivers that are already registered

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I am writing a web part against a list.  The first thing I do in the web part is verify that my custom event receivers are registered on the list.  If they are not, I register the programmatically.

I have noticed that if I try to register an event that is already registered, I get no errors and no “Extra” events are registered.

My question is:  Would it be more efficient to just register the events each time the web part loads rather than iterating through each event in the event receiver list and doing compares to see if each of my event receivers are there?

**Edit**

About the Property bag suggestions.  After thinking a bit more about it, this will not be a feasable solution. The reason that I am "verifying" that the receivers are there is because we have 3rd party webparts that are attached to the same list.  These have, in the past, actually unregistered our custom receivers.  Setting a flag in the property bag will just let me know that I have verified once, but won't tell me if they get removed by another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that SharePoint uses to update an event receiver collection is obfuscated, so there's no way to know for sure. I would guess that the first step is a check similar to what you are doing manually. I'm inclined to go with what's easiest until you identify that performance is an issue, in which case I would set a flag on the list's `RootFolder`'s property bag.

Answer (score 2):

I unsure if this is best approach. I have seen a code that does something similar to your requirement. What it does is that once the EventHandler are added they stored a flag in the SPWeb Property Bag. Next time you just check the Property bag for the flag if it is there dont register the eventhandler . Refer this [link](http://trentacular.com/2009/06/sharepoint-the-wicked-spwebproperties-propertybag/) for more information about the property bag. Final note you might need more permission to set the property bag value to SPWeb

Comment: Thanks Kusek.  Permissions shouldn't be an issue.  I am already using elevated permissions to register.  The only down side I see to this Idea, is that multiple web parts "may" exist on multiple sites.

Comment: Guid of the WebPart or something of that sort should help you to get the unique value.